# Are crossbows in Baldur's Gate 3 not limited to 1 shot per turn?

Tags: baldurs-gate-3

As I understand it, in general BG3 is not only using WotC's IP for D&D, it also is using the 5e rules to resolve actions in combat. However, there seems to be no limit to how many shots one can make with a crossbow.

In the 5e rules, crossbows have the **loading** property:

> **Loading**. Because of the time required to load this weapon, you can fire only one piece of ammunition from it when you use an action, bonus action, or reaction to fire it, regardless of the number of attacks you can normally make.

Has this rule just been dropped for the comupter game, or do the characters have some special ability that allows them to shoot multiple times (for example, I have the Githyanki fighter in my group, and she can do 2 attacks per turn at level 5).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quite simply, this rule is not present in Baldur's Gate 3.

So you haven't missed anything - it's simply one of many small differences that emerged from translating 5e into the digital space.

Comment: Thanks, what is the common protocol on this site -- can I just accept-check, or should I wait for 24h, for other takes, like we do it on RPG.se?

Comment: @NobodytheHobgoblin A lot of answers on RPG.se involve interpreting written down rules or giving advice about a certain situation; as such those answers are inherently subjective and it makes sense to wait just a bit to see if someone has a better answer. In the case of a *lot* of gaming.se questions, however, the answer is an objective fact and there's not really anything that could benefit from a second opinion.