Is the list of classes available in Baldur's Gate 3 identical to the list of classes available in D&D 5E?
Baldur's Gate 3 is based off of Dungeons & Dragons Fifth Edition (5E), which has several classes. I'm curious if all the official classes in 5E are available in Baldur's Gate 3. Additionally, I'm also wondering if there are any classes in Baldur's Gate 3 which aren't available in 5E.
In other words, is the list of classes available in Baldur's Gate 3 identical to the list of classes available in D&D 5E?

This question, at present, is absolutely far too broad for a single answer. You are asking for the contents of an entire wiki here. If you have specific questions about specific class features or abilities, you should ask those.

Also check out this question, it might have answers for (some of) your questions: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/405448/25490

I've updated this question so it's more align with what you originally proposed in your meta here. As @LessPop_MoreFizz, the original version of your question was too broad for a single question, but this trimmed down version is perfectly fine. I'll post more details about all this, including the best approach to getting all your questions answered, in your meta later today.

Baldur's Gate 3 includes all 12 principal base classes that have been around for at least two editions (the Warlock, being the newest entry, was introduced during 3.5, and turned core for the 4th edition), and have been published as such in the 5th edition Player's Handbook.
With the subclasses it's a bit more complicated:



BASE CLASS
5E core
BG3
BG3 CP#30




Barbarian
2: Path of the Berserker, Path of the Totem Warrior
3: Berserker, Wildheart, Wild Magic
Path of Giants


Bard
2: College of Lore, College of Valour
3: College of Lore, College of Valour, College of Swords
College of Glamour


Cleric
7 Domains: Knowledge, Life, Light, Nature, Tempest, Trickery, War
7: idem
Extra domain: Death


Druid
2: Circle of the Land, Circle of the Moon
3: Circle of the Land, Circle of the Moon, Circle of the Spores
Circle of Stars


Fighter
3: Champion, Battle Master, Eldritch Knight
3: idem
Arcane Archer


Monk
3: Way of the Open Hand, Way of Shadow, Way of the Four Elements
3: idem
Drunken Master


Paladin
3 (4): Oath of Devotion, Oath of the Ancients, Oath of Vengeance
4: idem + Oathbreaker (but mentioned in DMG 5E)
Oath of the Crown


Ranger
2: Hunter, Beast Master
3: Hunter, Beast Master, Gloom Stalker
Swarmkeeper


Rogue
3: Thief, Assassin, Arcane Trickster
3: idem
Swashbuckler


Sorcerer
2: Wild Magic, Draconic Bloodline
3: idem + Storm Sorcery
Shadow Magic


Warlock
3: The Archfey, The Fiend, The Great Old One
3: idem
Hexblade


Wizard
8 Schools: Abjuration, Conjuration, Divination, Enchantment, Evocation, Illusion, Necromancy, Transmutation
8: idem
Bladesinging



Most of the additional subclasses from the game, including those from the Community Patch #30, have been published in the supplementary 5E sourcebooks: the Bard subclasses College of Swords and College of Glamour, the Ranger subclass Gloom Stalker, the Sorcerer subclasses Storm Sorcery and Shadow Magic, the Fighter's Arcane Archer, the Monk's Drunken Master, the Rogue's subclass Swashbuckler, and the Warlock subclass Hexblade were published in Xanathar's Guide to Everything, and the Druid's Circle of the Spores and Circle of Stars, the Barbarian's Wild Magic, the Ranger's Swarmkeeper, and the Wizard's Bladesinging in Tasha's Cauldron of Everything.
CP#30's Paladin subclass Oath of the Crown originates in the Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide and the Barbarian subclass Path of Giants in Bigby Presents - Glory of the Giants (as Path of the Giant).
The only two outliers here are the Barbarian's subclass Wildheart, which is Larian's reinterpretation of Path of the Totem Warrior (see e.g. here), and the Cleric's Death Domain that was added by CP#30, which is actually a core subclass (from the Dungeon Master's Guide).
As for the Artificer base class: this was introduced in the Eberron campaign setting, already during the 3rd edition (but as a Wizard specialization already as far back as 2E), and made its reappearance during the 4th and 5th in non-core rulebooks. As jwodder points out in their answer, it was published in Tasha's Cauldron of Everything, which is a sourcebook (expanding on the Player's Handbook, Dungeon Master's Guide, and the Monster Manual).
Tasha's Cauldron of Everything was published in 2020, whereas development on Baldur's Gate 3 already started in 2016: apart from the exclusion of the Artificer base class from the core rulebooks, this could account for this class not having made it into the game.
There is a mod available to remedy that, though.

What does 'idem' mean?

@Daemons the same.

Oddly enough, they didn't use the Artificer, but they did use the Tasha rule that you can decide which attributes get +2 and +1, instead of that being determined by your race. OTOH, that is probably much, much easier to implement than a whole new class.

I disagree with your use of "5E" in this answer/the table.  It looks like you're only considering the PHB, but the querent asked about "official classes in 5E", which should include any non-homebrew/non-UA content.  This is particularly bad as your table implies BG3 includes extra subclasses that aren't in 5E (e.g. Swords bard), when these are indeed official 5E subclasses.

@AndrzejDoyle Yes, good point, the label "5E" should be expanded on. Nevertheless, I don't mention anywhere the other classes aren't official ones, just that the core classes were all published as such in the core rulebooks (Artificer being a later addition), and the additional subclassescome from non-core (but official) rulebooks. (Is it better now?)

@AndrzejDoyle (And with "now" I meant after the last edit.. :)

Not quite.  Although Baldur's Gate 3 includes all 12 classes listed in the 5e Player's Handbook, it does not include the Artificer class printed (in various forms) in Wayfinder's Guide to Eberron, Eberron: Rising from the Last War, and Tasha's Cauldron of Everything.
On the other hand, Baldur's Gate 3 introduces no new classes.
